# Como realizar o controle de versão da aplicação em produção?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Ao usar o `TFS`, temos todo o controle de versão dos arquivos de uma aplicação.

Então, a cada modificação de arquivos, por parte de inúmeros membros de uma equipe, cada arquivo terá sua versão...

Um **exemplo** que pode acontecer...

Foi realizado o desenvolvimento de algumas funcionalidades, e foi mandado em produção...
Enquanto isso, foram sido desenvolvidos vários outras funcionalidades, que são independentes e também que se comunicação com funcionalidades já existentes...
Caso seja enviado para produção essas novas funcionalidades, e aconteça algum erro "grande", como faço para voltar para a versão estável ?

Então, gostaria de saber, como fazer o controle da versão que foi compilada para produção, para caso haja algum problema drástico, conseguir voltar a versão estável inteira?

Comment: Não se faz controle de versão de código binário, só do fonte. Para isto é só copiar a versão anterior do executável. Em geral você tem em algum lugar. Se não tiver, volte o fonte para a versão anterior e compile-a. Claro que se tiver que voltar estrutura de banco de dados complica um pouco e em alguns casos se torna inviável voltar pra trás (sempre dá para viabilizar, mas precisa planejamento).

Comment: O TFS é apenas uma ferramenta para controlar as mudanças. O TFS pode usar os mesmos conceitos aplicados a GIT ou SVN. Ele tbm possui Branching, Merging e Labeling. Este último equivale ao Tagging no Git. Não uso TFS por isso não darei isso como uma resposta, apenas uma direção.

Comment: Continuando... Conforme o @bigown disse, não se versiona o executável final. Partindo do principio que só existe a implantação após a aplicação ter sido homologada, se acontecer algum erro grave, é necessário uma nova versão e não voltar a anterior, mas se mesmo assim precisar voltar, os passos para isso deverão estar documentado no processo de implantação como o *rollback* da implantação.

Answer (score 3):

Sua pergunta é antiga aqui, na época a solução era diferente, mas atualmente muita coisa evoluiu, e acredito que pode ajudar outras pessoas que possam estar na mesma situação.

O TFS (Team Foundation Server), é uma ferramenta que vai além do simples controle de versões de aplicações, o TFS é um Stack bem completo de DevOps da Microsoft.

Podemos dizer hoje, que o TFS possui *"duas versões"*:

- On-Premisses: TFS, que você instala na sua rede, você gerencia bkp, atualização, etc
- Cloud: VSTS  (Visual Studio Team Services), que você não precisa se preocupar com instalação, configuração, bkp, update, etc.

O TFS/VSTS possui uma série de funcionalidades, que se bem utilizadas, permitem realizar esse mapeamento de versões, como o @Rod estava buscando, são essas funcionalidades:

1. Controle de Versões, utilizando repositórios GIT e/ou TFVC
2. Planejamento Ágil, para gestão de tarefas, Scrum, Kanban
3. Build Automatizada, para validar se o projeto está ok, e gerar os pacotes para implantação
4. Deployment automatizado, para implantar a aplicação em todos os ambientes, com ciclo de aprovação, agendamento de horario, etc.

Bom, voltando agora ao ponto da pergunta.

Como o VSTS/TFS possui uma funcionalidade voltada ao deployment automatizado, você consegue validar qual era a versão do build que foi implementado no ambiente da ultima vez, e assim, realizar o deployment com essa versão especifica novamente no ambiente.[image: print do Release Management]

Sobre a primeira imagem:
Este é o Dashboard de Deployments, cada caixinha verde, é referente a um ambiente onde foi realizado o Deployment, a parte onde consta a build, é a versão da build que foi utilizado no deploy, então, caso você precise voltar a versão, pode ver qual build foi no deploy, e assim, iniciar um novo utilizando essa build garantindo que a versão funcional está em produção.